# What is Apple recommended or suggested position of True or false case in AlertView

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview, human-interface

I'm building app in which I've no design for alerts so client suggested us to use native Alerts. There are more than dozens of native alerts used in App.

So I'm looking for some recommended or suggested from Apple that what will be position of true or false case (YES, NO. OK, Cancel and etc with 2 options including true or false case)?

I googled but didn't find any statement which tells us about this.
Attached image of Apple ID Sign in alertview, in both True is on Right side and False is on Left side shown. I want some written format or need your suggestion how to place positions of both button ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: please refer this post that may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582795/uialertview-where-the-cancel-button-should-be

Answer (score 0):

I google and helped from Nishant mentioned link in comment I found.

**Place buttons where people expect them.** In general, buttons people are most likely to tap should be on the right. Cancel buttons should always be on the left. https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/alerts/